# Close dialog on click (anywhere)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, modal-dialog

Is there a default option to close a jQuery dialog by clicking somewhere on the screen instead of the close icon?

Comment: This post may help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384067/how-to-dismiss-the-dialog-with-click-on-outside-of-the-dialog

Answer (score 125):

> Edit: Here's a plugin I authored that extends the jQuery UI Dialog to include
>   closing when clicking outside plus other features:
>   https://github.com/jasonday/jQuery-UI-Dialog-extended

Here are 3 methods to close a jquery UI dialog when clicking outside popin:

If the dialog is modal/has background overlay:
http://jsfiddle.net/jasonday/6FGqN/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#dialog").dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 100,
        modal: true,
        open: function() {
            jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click', function() {
                jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');
            })
        }
    });
});
```

If dialog is non-modal Method 1:
http://jsfiddle.net/jasonday/xpkFf/

```
// Close Pop-in If the user clicks anywhere else on the page
jQuery('body')
    .bind('click', function(e) {
        if(jQuery('#dialog').dialog('isOpen')
            && !jQuery(e.target).is('.ui-dialog, a')
            && !jQuery(e.target).closest('.ui-dialog').length
        ) {
            jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');
        }
    });
```

Non-Modal dialog Method 2:
http://jsfiddle.net/jasonday/eccKr/

```
$(function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false, 
        minHeight: 100,
        width: 342,
        draggable: true,
        resizable: false,
        modal: false,
        closeText: 'Close',
        open: function() {
            closedialog = 1;
            $(document).bind('click', overlayclickclose); },
        focus: function() { 
            closedialog = 0; },
        close: function() { 
            $(document).unbind('click'); }
    });

    $('#linkID').click(function() {
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        closedialog = 0;
    });

    var closedialog;

    function overlayclickclose() {
        if (closedialog) {
            $('#dialog').dialog('close');
        }
        //set to one because click on dialog box sets to zero
        closedialog = 1;
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice answer! The only one I've seen that deals with the non-modal usage of the dialog.

Comment: Did you know that you only have to write `jQuery` in its long form once? By wrapping your code in `(function($) { .... })(jQuery);`, you can use `$` no matter if `noConflict` has been used or not.

Answer (score 17):

When creating a JQuery Dialog window, JQuery inserts a ui-widget-overlay class.  If you bind a click function to that class to close the dialog, it should provide the functionality you are looking for.

Code will be something like this (untested):

```
$('.ui-widget-overlay').click(function() { $("#dialog").dialog("close"); });
```

**Edit:**
The following has been tested for **Kendo** as well:

```
$('.k-overlay').click(function () {
            var popup = $("#dialogId").data("kendoWindow");
            if (popup)
                popup.close();
        });
```

Comment: It's worth adding, you should add 'body' to the overlay click event declaration, as if the overlay doesn't exist when creating the event, it won't be applied. 

    $('body').on('click', '.ui-widget-overlay', function() { $("#dialog").dialog("close"); });

Answer (score 8):

If you have several dialogs that could be opened on a page, this will allow any of them to be closed by clicking on the background:

```
$('body').on('click','.ui-widget-overlay', function() {
    $('.ui-dialog').filter(function () {
    return $(this).css("display") === "block";
    }).find('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close');
});
```

(Only works for modal dialogs, as it relies on '.ui-widget-overlay'. And it does close **all** open dialogs any time the background of one of them is clicked.)

Answer (score 7):

If you'd like to do it for all dialogs throughout the site try the following code...

```
$.extend( $.ui.dialog.prototype.options, { 
    open: function() {
        var dialog = this;
        $('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click', function() {
            $(dialog).dialog('close');
        });
    }   

});
```

Answer (score 6):

This post may help:

http://www.jensbits.com/2010/06/16/jquery-modal-dialog-close-on-overlay-click/

See also [How to close a jQuery UI modal dialog by clicking outside the area covered by the box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368524/how-to-close-a-jquery-ui-modal-dialog-by-clicking-outside-the-area-covered-by-the/7375708#7375708) for explanation of when and how to apply `overlay` click or live event depending on how you are using dialog on page.

Answer (score 5):

In some cases, Jason's answer is overkill. And `$('.ui-widget-overlay').click(function(){ $("#dialog").dialog("close"); });` doesn't always work with dynamic content.

The solution that I find works in all cases is:

```
$('body').on('click','.ui-widget-overlay',function(){ $('#dialog').dialog('close'); });
```

Comment: in what scenarios do any of my solutions not work? (out of curiosity) as most of my development is for dynamic content - my overlay and non-overlay methods have worked every time.

Comment: I haven't found it to be an issue, but your above is more a comment than answer - additionally, `.on` is more recent and delegate may be a safer option.

Answer (score 1):

If the code of the previous posts doesn't work, give this a try:

```
$("a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close")[0].click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same problem, I have created a small plugin that enables to close a dialog when clicking outside of it whether it a modal or non-modal dialog. It supports one or multiple dialogs on the same page.

More information on my website here: http://www.coheractio.com/blog/closing-jquery-ui-dialog-widget-when-clicking-outside

Laurent

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".ui-widget-overlay").click(function () {
    $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-closethick").trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for your answer. I'm reviewing your answer because it has been flagged for quality review due to it's terseness. In this case your answer seems to be useful and maybe correct, so I won't delete it. However, it would be really helpful if you could add some text around it explaining what it does, how it works, and how it addresses the OP's problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but this is a solution that worked for me. Perfect if your modal is inside the overlay tag. So, the modal will close when you click anywhere outside the modal content.

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal">  
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <p>HELLO WORLD!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on("click", function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).has(".modal-content").length) {
    $(".modal").hide();
  }
});
```

Here is a [**working example**](https://codepen.io/dragoeco/pen/rwMYQJ)