# JQuery: Click anywhere on body to close modal dialog for this code

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

The same question is asked [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675893/jquery-close-dialog-on-click-anywhere) but it doesn't state the source, and the solution given is not directly applicable in my case afaik.
I might get modded down for this, but I am asking anyway.
**My Entire Code:**

```
<html><head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/humanity/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body><div id="dialog" title="Title Box">
        <p>Stuff here</p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#dialog").dialog({
          bgiframe: true, autoOpen: false, height: 100, modal: true
        });
      });
    </script>
    <a href="#" onclick="jQuery('#dialog').dialog('open'); return false">Click to view</a>
</body></html>
```

All script files are third party hosted, and I would want to keep it that way.

***How do I get "click anywhere (outside the box)to close the modal box" functionality?***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/themes/humanity/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="dialog" title="Title Box">
   <p>Stuff here</p>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(
    function() {
     jQuery("#dialog")
      .dialog(
       {
        bgiframe: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 100,
        modal: true
       }
      );
     jQuery('body')
      .bind(
       'click',
       function(e){
        if(
         jQuery('#dialog').dialog('isOpen')
         && !jQuery(e.target).is('.ui-dialog, a')
         && !jQuery(e.target).closest('.ui-dialog').length
        ){
         jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');
        }
       }
      );
    }
   );
  </script>
  <a href="#" onclick="jQuery('#dialog').dialog('open'); return false">Click to view</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer +1. but the code does not work. And I am a jquery neonate.

Comment: You're right, the first version was a bit rushed. The new one does work as you described. ;)

Comment: i like SO for this: quick straight answers. sister sites suffer from lack of traffic though.

Answer (score 3):

I know this has already has an accepted answer, but maybe this will help someone. It seems to me that it would be more efficient to bind a click onto the overlay div when the modal is opened. There is no need to unbind because jQueryUI destroys the overlay div on close.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#dialog").dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 100,
        modal: true,
        open: function(){
            jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click',function(){
                jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is an old thread, but it should be noted that this approach only works if the dialog is using the modal:true setting. That setting adds the overlay which is needed in this solution. However, if you are using that setting, this answer is better/cleaner than the accepted answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and tell me if it works (I don't have time to try right now)

```
$('body').click(function(){
   if( $('#dialog').dialog("isOpen") ) {
      $('#dialog').dialog("close")
   }
});
```

Comment: This would close the dialog, if the user clicks anywhere (including inside the dialog element).