# jQuery-UI close modal dialog on background click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm toying with jQuery UI, and I like how this demo works:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-message

However, when a dialog comes up, the only way to close it is to click one of the interface buttons inside the dialog - how could I extend this to close any/a given dialog when the user clicks on the background layer covering up the page?

I saw where users can hit "escape", but frankly I don't think most users will think to do this (I didn't until I saw it as an option), however it might occur to them to click away from the message.

Is there an event/option I'm missing that I can tap into?

Comment: I found the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675893/jquery-close-dialog-on-click-anywhere to work better than the ones listed here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That should do the trick:

```
$(".ui-widget-overlay").click(function(){
    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").trigger('click');
});
```

Click on `.ui-widget-overlay` will trigger the click on the close button

Cheers

G.

Answer (score 14):

I've found the previous to be finicky at times, here's a simple fix:

```
$(".ui-widget-overlay").live('click', function(){
   $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: You know I had to ask about live a few days after this, heh.

Comment: How would you apply the background click in IE6 environment? It's failing on my side at the moment. I'm using latest [Github]https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/commit/04667b15180ddbbc88af9a0fe30ace91aef2ae15

Comment: live is better according to my testing!

Answer (score 13):

This one will definitely work, since it matters when the overlay is in the dom or not.

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-widget-overlay', function(){
  $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

just to add in case anyone run's into this problem - if you have multiple dialogs stacked on top of each other then the following will close *just* the dialog that's at the top:

```
$(".ui-widget-overlay").live("click", function () {
            $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", $(this).prev()).trigger('click');
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the preferred method to use when dealing with newer versions of Jquery.

```
$(".ui-widget-overlay").on("click", function(){
    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").trigger('click');
});
```