# How to close a jQuery UI modal dialog by clicking outside the area covered by the box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I am using jQuery 1.6 and jQuery UI. I successfully implemented a [modal dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) window which width is almost 50% of my application web page' width. I would like to give to the user *another way to close the dialog* so that when he\she clicks outside the area covered on the page by the "modal box", this one will be closed as if the user clicked on the "standard" "x" button on the top-right of that.

**How can I do that?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To clarify, the answer by Victor only works if the dialog is set to `autoOpen: true`, the default value of the dialog, **and** you do not open the dialog **again** with an event. If you open the dialog with an event like `click` at any point whether `autoOpen` is set to `true` or `false`, then you have to use `jQuery.live`.

Fiddle demonstrating failure of overlay `click` event with `autoOpen: false`: http://jsfiddle.net/GKfZM/

Fiddle demonstrating how `live` works with `autoOpen: false` and with `click` event: http://jsfiddle.net/GKfZM/1/

**Summary:** Victor's answer only works under certain conditions.

[Tutorial link](http://www.jensbits.com/2010/06/16/jquery-modal-dialog-close-on-overlay-click/)

Comment: notice thant `live()` is deprecated since jQuery version 1.7, you should use `on()` instead.

Answer (score 10):

**Update**

This was the initial answer:

```
$(".ui-widget-overlay").click (function () {
     $("#your-dialog-id").dialog( "close" );
});
```

This is the working solution:

```
$('.ui-widget-overlay').live('click', function() {
     $('#your-dialog-id').dialog( "close" );
});
```

Comment: In my case I should use the `jQuery.live` method. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

How about this way，this way you can close the dialog whatever it open from where and which id. It's a global function:

```
   $("body").on("click",".ui-widget-overlay",function() {
     $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").click();
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options for the close model dialog box

```
$('#your-dialog-id').modal('toggle');
```

OR

you can use the click event directly when you click outside box

```
$("#your-dialog-id .close").click()
```