# Closing Modal dialog on focusout

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I am using a Jquery Modal dialog widget and I am trying to add an event that will close the dialog when the user click outside of the Modal Dialog div, but currently, my Modal dialog is closing immediatly after it open.

Here a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/WYRtr/

html :

```
    <div id='password_dialogue' title="Modification de mot de passe">

            <h3>Modifier votre mot de passe</h3>

            <label>Mot de passe actuel :<span style='color:red;'> *</span></label><br/>
            <input type='password' name='pwd' id='pwd' /><br/><br/>

            <label>Nouveau mot de passe :<span style='color:red;'> *</span></label><br/>
            <input type='password' name='newPwd' id='newPwd' /><br/><br/>

            <input type='submit' name='validerPwd' value='sauvegarder' />

    </div>
<button id='password'>Modifier mot de passe</button><br/>
```

Jquery :

```
$(function() {

    $( "#password_dialogue" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      width:600,
      height:400,
      draggable: false,
      resizable:false,
      closeOnEscape: true,
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
      }
    });

    $( "#password" ).click(function() {
        $( "#password_dialogue" ).focus();
      $( "#password_dialogue" ).dialog( "open" );
    });

    $("#password_dialogue").focusout(function(){
        $( "#password_dialogue" ).dialog( "close" );
     });
  });
```

I seen a solution about my problem here : [Click outside non-modal dialog to close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919229/click-outside-non-modal-dialog-to-close) but in this solution, the modal dialog is closing even when we click on the title bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set it to `modal:true` and use the `.ui-widget-overlay` as a target for closing.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WYRtr/1/

```
$('body').on('click', '.ui-widget-overlay', function(e){
  $('#password_dialogue').dialog('close');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {

    $( "#password_dialogue" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      width:600,
      height:400,
      draggable: false,
      resizable:false,
      closeOnEscape: true,
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
      }
    });

    $( "#password" ).click(function(event) {    
      event.stopPropagation();       
      $( "#password_dialogue" ).dialog( "open" );
      $( "#pwd" ).focus();
    });

    $("body").click(function(){
        $( "#password_dialogue" ).dialog( "close" );
     });
  });
```