# How to dismiss the dialog with click on outside of the dialog?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, dialog, android-dialog

I have implemented a custom dialog for my application. I want to implement that when the user clicks outside the dialog, the dialog will be dismissed.
What do I have to do for this?

Answer (score 385, accepted):

You can use `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);` which will close the dialog if you touch outside of the dialog.

Something like,

```
  Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context)
  dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

Or if your Dialog in non-model then,

1 - Set the flag-`FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL` for your dialog's window attribute

```
Window window = this.getWindow();
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
```

2 - Add another flag to windows properties,, `FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH` - this one is for dialog to receive touch event outside its visible region.

3 - Override `onTouchEvent()` of dialog and check for action type. if the action type is
'`MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE`' means, user is interacting outside the dialog region. So in this case, you can dimiss your dialog or decide what you wanted to perform.
view plainprint?

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)  
{  

       if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE){  
        System.out.println("TOuch outside the dialog ******************** ");  
               this.dismiss();  
       }  
       return false;  
}
```

For more info look at [How to dismiss a custom dialog based on touch points?](http://iserveandroid.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-dismiss-custom-dialog-based-on.html) and
[How to dismiss your non-modal dialog, when touched outside dialog region](http://iserveandroid.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-dismiss-your-non-modal-dialog.html)

Comment: This works great except that the activity underneath also reacts to the touch event.  Is there some way to prevent this?

Comment: Yeah. window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL); causes this problem. I've posted a solution below :)

Comment: Is it possible to propagate 'on-touch-outside' events to the underneath activity using a non-custom dialog too?

Comment: @howettl I have solved your problem in my solution **which I have posted below** where I don't need to set any flags to window.

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat - Please look at this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/VhaiIMl6E_w . They nicely described it.

Comment: When dialog is dismiss i give slide down animation but when i opened dialog at and without closing dialog I am pressing minimize button of my phone at that time my dialog is auto matically dismiss and some effect with slide down which is not good so how to prevent to dismiss dialog at that time. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22):

Simply use

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

Comment: I know that this should the right answer, but doesn't work for me, and I just don't know why.

Answer (score 17):

You can use this implementation of onTouchEvent. It prevent from reacting underneath activity to the touch event (as mentioned howettl).

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent ( MotionEvent event ) {
  // I only care if the event is an UP action
  if ( event.getAction () == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ) {
    // create a rect for storing the window rect
    Rect r = new Rect ( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    // retrieve the windows rect
    this.getWindow ().getDecorView ().getHitRect ( r );
    // check if the event position is inside the window rect
    boolean intersects = r.contains ( (int) event.getX (), (int) event.getY () );
    // if the event is not inside then we can close the activity
    if ( !intersects ) {
      // close the activity
      this.finish ();
      // notify that we consumed this event
      return true;
    }
  }
  // let the system handle the event
  return super.onTouchEvent ( event );
}
```

Source: http://blog.twimager.com/2010/08/closing-activity-by-touching-outside.html

Answer (score 9):

Or, if you're customizing the dialog using a theme defined in your style xml, put this line in your theme:

```
<item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
```

Comment: This does not work for me on Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 WiFi. `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);` does work wonderfully.

Answer (score 9):

This method should completely avoid activities below the grey area retrieving click events.

**Remove** this line if you have it:

```
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
```

Put this on your activity created

```
getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH, LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH);
```

then override the touch event with this

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
{
    if(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN == ev.getAction())
    {
        Rect dialogBounds = new Rect();
        getWindow().getDecorView().getHitRect(dialogBounds);
        if (!dialogBounds.contains((int) ev.getX(), (int) ev.getY())) {
            // You have clicked the grey area
            displayYourDialog();
            return false; // stop activity closing
        }
    }

    // Touch events inside are fine.
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

to close dialog on touch outside.

And if you don't want to close on touch outside, use the code below:

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try this :-

```
AlterDialog alterdialog;
alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

or

```
alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
```

And if you have a `AlterDialog.Builder` Then you can try this:-

```
alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);
```

Answer (score 5):

This code is use for when use click on dialogbox that time hidesoftinput and when user click outer side of dialogbox that time both softinput and  dialogbox are close.

```
dialog = new Dialog(act) {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Tap anywhere to close dialog.
        Rect dialogBounds = new Rect();
        getWindow().getDecorView().getHitRect(dialogBounds);
        if (!dialogBounds.contains((int) event.getX(),
                (int) event.getY())) {
            // You have clicked the grey area
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) act
                    .getSystemService(act.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(dialog
                    .getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
            dialog.dismiss();
            // stop activity closing
        } else {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) act
                    .getSystemService(act.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(dialog
                    .getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }

        return true;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution, this code was taken from android source code of `Window` 
You should just add these Two methods to your dialog source code.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {        
    if (isShowing() && (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
            && isOutOfBounds(getContext(), event) && getWindow().peekDecorView() != null)) {
        hide();
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean isOutOfBounds(Context context, MotionEvent event) {
    final int x = (int) event.getX();
    final int y = (int) event.getY();
    final int slop = ViewConfiguration.get(context).getScaledWindowTouchSlop();
    final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    return (x < -slop) || (y < -slop)
            || (x > (decorView.getWidth()+slop))
            || (y > (decorView.getHeight()+slop));
}
```

This solution doesnt have this problem :

> This works great except that the activity underneath also reacts to the touch event. Is there some way to prevent this? –  howettl

Comment: Cant you just make your dialog touch modal if you dont want other windows recieving events?

Answer (score 3):

Following has worked for me:

```
myDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `dialog.setCancelable(false);` from your activity/fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `background` occupying all the screen size `transparent` and listen to the `onClick` event to `dismiss` it.

Comment: Very bad answer! Of course this can be done, but please do it the right way!

Answer (score 0):

I tried some answers still I faced a problem like when I press outside the dialog dialog was hiding but a dimmed view was showing, and pressing again would go to the parent activity. But actually I wanted to go the parent activity after first click.
So what I did was

```
dialog.setOnCancelListener(this);
```

and changed my activity to implement `DialogInterface.OnCancelListener` with

```
@Override
public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
     finish();
}
```

And boom, it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code

```
    dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {

            if(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN == ev.getAction())
            {
                Rect dialogBounds = new Rect();
                dialog. getWindow().getDecorView().getHitRect(dialogBounds);
                if (!dialogBounds.contains((int) ev.getX(), (int) ev.getY())) {
                    // You have clicked the grey area
                    UiUtils.hideKeyboard2(getActivity());
                    return false; // stop activity closing
                }
            }
            getActivity().dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Try this one . you can hide the keyboard when you touch outside