# Android custom dialog box window dismisses when clicked outside?

Tags: android, dialog

My problem is when dialog box is showing at that time may i click outside the dialog box, at that time my dialog box is dismissed automatically. What can i do. Please send answers with code. Thanks.

Comment: Here is an [answer with code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384067/how-to-dismiss-the-dialog-with-click-on-outside-of-the-dialog).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi this line is used to dismiss dialog Box.

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

This line is is used for does not dismiss dialog Box.

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```