# Popup window dismissal

Tags: android, android-layout

I was hoping to get the answer for this, I have tried very much to dismiss the popup window when I click outside, but it is not dismissing, anybody know why? Also it is not going back when I click back button.

```
public void onButtonPopup (View target) {
       // Make a View from our XML file
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;
        int height = size.y; 

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.samplescreens, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.closeLayout));


        pwindo = new PopupWindow(layout, width-40, height-(height/4), true);
        pwindo.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

        pwindo.update();
        pwindo.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    }
public void onButtonInPopup (View target) {
        //back_dim_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pwindo.dismiss();
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android popup window dismissal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121232/android-popup-window-dismissal)

Comment: and what is 'very much' ?

Comment: Also see post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554855/click-outside-of-popup-to-dismiss-it

Comment: maybe change the order or this 2 statements: `pwindo.update();
        pwindo.setOutsideTouchable(true);`

Comment: tried those methods it is not responding

Comment: possible duplicate of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554855/click-outside-of-popup-to-dismiss-it

Comment: those did not solve my problem. @MiStr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it! Changed the order:

```
pwindo = new PopupWindow(layout, width-40, height-(height/4), true);

        pwindo.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        pwindo.setTouchable(true);
        pwindo.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
        pwindo.setTouchInterceptor(customPopUpTouchListenr);

    pwindo.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

it works now

Answer (score 0):

One problem from your code is you've written `pwindo = new PopupWindow(layout, width-40, height-(height/4), true);` in which forth parameter is `true` i.e. keep popup window focusable. This is the mistake, as though you say `pwindo.setOutsideTouchable(true);` you've already defined that popup window should be focusable. Make that forth parameter to `false`. Still if you're not able to dismiss it, then before dismissing a popup like `pwindo.dismiss()` write this line, `pwindo.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources()));`.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: No it is not working still, I have edited my code, showing the dismiss method.@giga_abhi

Comment: and I need to put the focusable to true, because I have buttons and edit text's in the popup

Comment: Try putting `pwindo.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources()));` before dismissing it! It worked for me.