# Prevend dialog from dismiss when clicking somewhere

Tags: java, android, dialog

How can I prevend a dialog from dismissing when I click somewhere outside the dialog?

Comment: Duplicate ???http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384067/how-to-dismiss-the-dialog-with-click-on-outside-of-the-dialog?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

use `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);` for more details [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCanceledOnTouchOutside(boolean)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCanceledOnTouchOutside%28boolean%29)