# Start activity using the same Dialog

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have created an activity displayed inside a Dialog using

```
<activity
   android:theme="@style/Theme.Dialog"  >
</activity>
```

It works pretty well. However, I would like to start a second activity from this dialog and I would like it to be displayed inside the same Dialog. The goal is that if the user click outside the Dialog, it closes the 2 activities.

For now, if I start the second activity, (also using the Dialog theme), it goes over the first one and if we click outside the Dialog, it closes only the second activity and comes back to the first..

Thanks By Advance,
Valentin

Answer (score 0):

If the second dialog is closed because the user click outside of the dialog, you could notify the first dialog to close itself too. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384067/how-to-dismiss-the-dialog-with-click-on-outside-of-the-dialog) might help.