# Detect clicks outside of a View

Tags: android

I have a view declared as such:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
myView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.background, null);
```

I want to detect clicks outside of myView, how can I do this?

So this background.xml is a small relativelayout that pops up when the user clicks on a button. It has an edit text so I do this to gain focus to it and allow to type on it:

```
response.setFocusable(true);
params.flags = params.flags & ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;
mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(myView, params);
```

Now if the user clicks outside this pop up(background.xml aka myView) I want to set the param.flags back to FLAG.NOT_FOCUSABLE

Comment: Hope this would help http://stackoverflow.com/a/8384124/1112882

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dummy view and make it fill parent and add onClickListener and do what you want on onClick.