# After spawning a Toast, how does the Gmail app detect a touch on any part of the screen but the Toast's content area?

Tags: android, android-toast

The `Gmail` app will spawn a `Toast` when the user has no internet connectivity.  I've noticed that this Toast will `dismiss` if the user touches anywhere **but** the Toast's content area. I can think of a naive way to emulate this that would add code all over the place.  Is there a good way to accomplish this with minimal code changes?

Comment: What's your naive way? Mine would be to cover the whole screen with a transparent view that detects touch events, and then put the toast on top of that... On the other hand, for a standard Dialog, looks like there's a [setCancelledOnTouchOutside](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384067/how-to-dismiss-the-dialog-with-click-on-outside-of-the-dialog) (Is this a Toast or a Dialog? A Toast automatically disappears after a while...)

Comment: My naive way was to set a bunch of listeners.  I actually don't mind your way!  How could you place the toast on top?  Would it be on top by default since it has a more global context?

Comment: @MattGibson It is a `Toast`.  I know it automatically disappears, but I also want it to disappear if the user touches outside of it.