# When does touching the screen outside an AlertDialog cancel the AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Suppose you have an `AlertDialog` with two buttons A and B. I have found that on some devices and some versions of android, if you touch any area of the screen around the dialog, the `AlertDialog` disappears. On other devices you are forced to select either A or B, so there is no way I can allow the user to cancel the action without adding a third ('Cancel') option to the `AlertDialog`. Is there any way to determine programmatically whether the third option is required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control it with `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);`

For more information :

[How to dismiss the dialog with click on outside of the dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384067/how-to-dismiss-the-dialog-with-click-on-outside-of-the-dialog)

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how I missed that other question.

Comment: @pbabcdefp No problem, sometimes its hard to find a right keyword for googling :) I have known that link

Answer (score 0):

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context)
 dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

Comment: Care to explain the solution a little bit?