# Android : parent RelativeLayout with whole height and width of screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have the following layout structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/wrapper_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.phoenetoaster.doitcalendar.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
            android:hint="@string/event_name"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                style="@style/textviews"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/when"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/value_when"
                style="@style/textviewsChangingText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/today"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!--Seekbar 2 -->
        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar_when"
            style="@style/seekbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                style="@style/textviews"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/time"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/value_time"
                style="@style/textviewsChangingText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/today"/>
        </RelativeLayout>


        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar_time"
            style="@style/seekbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            style="@style/buttons"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/create_event_in_calendar"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Which produces something like this:

[image]

I would like to ask how can i catch click outside of the form to hide the app to background?

I tried to set OnClick event to wrapper layout (Parent relative Layout) but this layout is not spread to whole height and width of the screen.

Should I add some other layouts?

How can I solve it please?

Many thanks for any advice

Comment: implement touch listener and on ACTION_DOWN cancel the screen whatever it is. If activity then make it finish() or any alertDialog then dismiss it.

It would be great if you share the code

Comment: I tried implement touch listener, but RelativeLayout is not overlaying the whole screen. ACTION_DOWN is some kind of gesture or is not?

Comment: in java code you are using an activity or what?

Comment: Yes, activity. MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN is able to catch in listener which is applied to layout. But if Relative layout has not full width and height is not called.

Comment: Maybe this can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384067/how-to-dismiss-the-dialog-with-click-on-outside-of-the-dialog

Comment: why should't you are using dialog with custom layout it will give you what you are looking for.