# how to dismiss dialog without using cancel?

Tags: android, eclipse, dialog

this dialog has two options. I want to dismiss a dialog by touching background but I don't know how.

```
public void dialog(  long id) {
    final int     position=(int) id;
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);      

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_checkbox);

        // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button

        Button yes = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.yes);
        Button no = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.no);

        yes.setTypeface(type);
        no.setTypeface(type);

        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        yes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            String number=contactnumber.get(position);
            String name=contactname.get(position);
                 contactnumber.remove(position);
                 contactname.remove(position);
                 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 dialog.dismiss();
                 str="del";
                 delete(name, number);

            }});

        no.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                edit(position);
                dialog.dismiss();

                }});
dialog.show();
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
dialog.getWindow().setLayout((6 * width)/7, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);





    }
```

I use this but not work

```
LinearLayout background = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.back);
background.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        SetBackground();
     // here I want to dismiss it after SetBackground() method 
      OptionDialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

The method SetBackground() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener()

Comment: call last line inside `OptionDialog.dismiss();` method ......

Comment: I don't think you need to attach a click listener for the background. The dialog should close automatically when clicked outside of its bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true); which will close the dialog if you touch outside of the dialog.

For more info look at this

[How to dismiss the dialog with click on outside of the dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384067/how-to-dismiss-the-dialog-with-click-on-outside-of-the-dialog)