# Close custom popup when it pressed outsided of the popup

Tags: android, dialog, android-popupwindow

I'm creating a custom popup using dialog in android. When using custom popup I'm using a cancel button for closing it. But now I want to close it by touching outside of that popup. how to to?

**What I've tried till now**

```
private void showDetails() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_base_menu);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

    text_cancel = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text_cancel);
    txt_create_group_chat = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txt_create_group_chat);
    txt_create_chat = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txt_create_chat);
    txt_create_chatroom = dialog.findViewById(R.id.txt_create_chatroom);

    text_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });

    txt_create_group_chat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent in = new Intent(mContext, CreateGroupChat.class);
            startActivity(in);
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    txt_create_chat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent in = new Intent(mContext, SearchActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    txt_create_chatroom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent in = new Intent(mContext, CreateChatroomActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();

}
```

Comment: Did you try `dialog.setCancelable(true);` ?

Comment: yes. not worked

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)
```

See Android developer [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html).

And create your Dialog like shown [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html), using an `AlertDialog.Builder`. This class offers the same constructor parameters as your utilized `Dialog`.

Additionally, this question already has an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384067/how-to-dismiss-the-dialog-with-click-on-outside-of-the-dialog#8384124).

Comment: Already user. but nor worked.

Comment: sorry not working with my code.

Comment: Maybe I can help you more in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157222/android-help).

Answer (score 0):

Three changes to be made before showing the Dialog:

```
 dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
 setCancelable(boolean)
```

The last thing that may help is to go to the layout `popup_base_menu` and change the root view `height` and `width` to:

```
 wrap_content
```

It should instead of `match_parent`.
All this change should be called before `dialog.show();`