# How to dismiss Android Dialog when click outside (using FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE)

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a dialog that I want to be dismissed when I click outside it. However, I don't want it to receive key events, because it's a volume dialog, and I want the activity to be able to receive the key volume up and down events. So I setted `FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE`, as you see below:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.MyDialogTheme);
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    Window window = alert.getWindow();
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
    alert.setView(view);
```

the problem is that, with this flag, I also can't make the dialog dismiss when a touch outside it happens.

All the solutions on [How to dismiss the dialog with click on outside of the dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384067/how-to-dismiss-the-dialog-with-click-on-outside-of-the-dialog) like `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);` wont work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Set the `flag-FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL`for your dialog's window attribute

```
Window window = this.getWindow();
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
```

2 - Add another flag to windows properties,,`FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH`- this one is for dialog to receive touch event outside its visible region.

3 - Override `onTouchEvent()`of dialog and check for action type. if the action type is '`MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE`' means, user is interacting outside the dialog region. So in this case, you can dimiss your dialog or decide what you wanted to perform. view plainprint?

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)  
{  

       if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE){  
        System.out.println("TOuch outside the dialog ******************** ");  
               this.dismiss();  
       }  
       return false;  
}
```