# jQuery Click outside dialog to close dialog

Tags: jquery, dialog

I'm new to jQuery and I did my best to throw together a function that on click opens a dialog message, and on click again closes it. What I want is to be able to click outside the dialog (anywhere on the screen) to close that dialog. How can I accomplish this in the setup I wrote? Also, is the code I currently have done correctly, or could I do it another, easier way?

**EDIT (10/17/12):**

I've updated the jQuery below to include part of Ryan Wheale's code, and this is the current status:

-"clickoutside" works for the currently open span

-Trying to open another span closes the current span and subsequently the new span

jQuery: http://www.eclipsisna.com/?ena=services

```
        $(".service_outline a, .service_title a, .service_price a").click(function() {
            $(this).closest("a").children("span").fadeToggle("fast", function() {
                $("span").not(this).fadeOut("fast");
            });
            $(this).one("clickoutside", function () {
                $("span").fadeOut("fast");
            });
        });
```

HTML:

```
    <td class="service_outline">
            <h11><a>Opti-<br><h12>Coat</h12><span><font color="#ffcc00">&bull;</font> Application of permanent, nano ceramic clear resin coating (replaces "Wax"/"Sealant")<br><font color="#ffcc00">&bull;</font> Extended durability for 2+ years<br><font color="#ffcc00">&bull;</font> $250<p><center><img src="images/opti-coat.png"></center></span></a></h11>
    </td>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675893/jquery-close-dialog-on-click-anywhere?rq=1

Comment: It's similar, but I need help within the context of the code I have written. That's what I don't understand.

Comment: If you can give an example of your markup, I can make my answer below more accurate to your scenario

Comment: Thanks Ryan, edited OP to show HTML markup example of service_outline class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Ben Allman's `clickoutside` plugin [found here](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-outside-events-plugin/), your life is easy:

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwheale/c89Vr/

```
var $links = $(".service_outline a, .service_title a, .service_price a"),
    $dialogs = $links.find( 'span' );

$links.on( 'click', showDialog );

/* -- EDIT: old code kept for historical purposes
$dialogs.on( 'clickoutside', hideDialogs );
*/

function showDialog (ev) {
    var $thisDialog = $(this).find( 'span' );

    /* -- EDIT: old code kept here for historical purposes
    $dialogs.not( $thisDialog ).fadeOut();
    */

    if(!$thisDialog.is(':visible')) {
        $thisDialog.fadeIn();

        /* -- EDIT: New code */
        setTimeout( function() {
            // IMPORTANT: touch events only supported when you use the 
            // modified plugin at the bottom of this example
            $thisDialog.one('clickoutside.closeDialog, touchstartoutside.closeDialog', function() {
                $thisDialog.unbind('.closeDialog').fadeOut();
            });
        }, 0);
    }
}

/* -- EDIT: old code kept here for historical purposes
function hideDialogs() {
    $dialogs.fadeOut();
}
*/

/*
 * jQuery outside events - v1.1 - 3/16/2010
 * http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-outside-events-plugin/
 * 
 * Copyright (c) 2010 "Cowboy" Ben Alman
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
 * http://benalman.com/about/license/

 * IMPORTANT: Modified to support touch events
 */
(function($,c,b){$.map("click dblclick mousemove mousedown mouseup mouseover mouseout change select submit keydown keypress keyup touchstart touchmove touchend".split(" "),function(d){a(d)});a("focusin","focus"+b);a("focusout","blur"+b);$.addOutsideEvent=a;function a(g,e){e=e||g+b;var d=$(),h=g+"."+e+"-special-event";$.event.special[e]={setup:function(){d=d.add(this);if(d.length===1){$(c).bind(h,f)}},teardown:function(){d=d.not(this);if(d.length===0){$(c).unbind(h)}},add:function(i){var j=i.handler;i.handler=function(l,k){l.target=k;j.apply(this,arguments)}}};function f(i){$(d).each(function(){var j=$(this);if(this!==i.target&&!j.has(i.target).length){j.triggerHandler(e,[i.target])}})}}})(jQuery,document,"outside");
```

Comment: This solutions requires a jQuery plugin - 'clickoutside' is not an event supported by jQuery.

Comment: @coderabbi - Thanks for that.  I have used ben allman's clickoutside plugin for so long that I didn't mention it.  I am writing a better solution now.

Comment: As I started to write a better solution, I could see that I was starting down the path of Ben Allman's solution... so I defer to that `:(` - I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I installed the plugin and updated the site to show your code, but now once a span is clicked, it fades in, then immediately fades out. You can see it in the link.

Comment: I updated my code (leaving old code in there... commented out).  See if that helps at all.

Comment: Same thing is happening, fades in then fades out on one click. Should still show in the OP's link.

Comment: I updated my code.  A timeout was needed to delay the binding of the "clickoutside" event.  If you would like an explanation of why the timeout is needed, let me know.

Comment: That works now, but it broke something else. Click a button to open a span, click again to close it, then click again to try and open it. On the 2nd open, the same fadeOut event occurs immediately. Would we have to setTimeout for that as well?

Comment: ok... sheesh I'm earning this one ;) - I added a check to make sure the dialog wasn't visible... mocks a true toggle behavior.

Comment: Hahaha - maybe award me points ;)  This was a good challenge.  I learned something out of it.

Comment: Done :) Do you know if there's any way to get "clickoutside" to work on mobile devices? As it is it doesn't look like it's supported.

Comment: hmmm, you can try modifying the plugin.  At the very beginning, you should see a space delimited list of events: `"click dblclick mousemove..."` - try adding `"touchstart touchend touchmove"` to the list.

Comment: Tried that, nothing. Would I have to have the jquery Mobile plugin installed to make it work?

Comment: I wish you had enough points to chat... anyhow, I don't have my phone right now, but you should be able to update my code to read `$thisDialog.one('clickoutside, touchstartoutside', function() { ...` - I don't want to update my example because this relies on a custom modification to Ben Alman's plugin.

Comment: That worked for the mobile, only now if the same icon is clicked twice on a mobile device, that same "immediate fade out on 2nd open" happens like the issue you resolved when you made the dialog visible. And yes, I wish I had enough points for chat.

Comment: Ok, so I was binding 2 events using the `one()` function of  jQuery, which means one of the events was getting unbound and not the other.  I was afraid this might cause problems and was being lazy.  I have updated the code accordingly.

Comment: I replaced lines 82-86 of Ben Alman's code w/ the custom plugin you added; same issue is happening.

Comment: ryan [dot] wheale [at] gmail [dot] com