# How to close the popover when clicked somewhere in the window using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, uipopovercontroller, popover

I am using angularjs for my front-end. I have created some popover windows. I want the popover window to be disappear when I click somewhere in the browser window. How can I do that using angularjs. Thanks in advance

Comment: How have you created popover windows? Have you used directives?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675893/jquery-close-dialog-on-click-anywhere  Where to put this code?  In link function of the directive!

Comment: Sorry for this non-clear content in the question. I am using angular-strap to create this popover. We don't need any directives for that. It's there as in-built feature. I want to hide that popover.