# Close modalbox on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to close the query ui modalbox when the user clicks on the rest of the page that is in the background.

I added this snippet to do this but it isn't working:

```
$('.ui-widget-overlay').on("click", function() {
    //Close the dialog
    $(this).find(".dialog").dialog("close");
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/VwCja/)

Comment: please add page code, why are you using the (this) in the query?

Comment: @DoryZidon Just curious but what's wrong with using (this) in the query? I've used it before. However, if this causes negative performance that I'm unaware of I may be regrouping when and how often I use (this) in my own code...

Comment: this is js has many meaning..could be tricky, but i assume jQuery gives you the element on which you click but I'd test it before..like alert this.tagName to see what comes up..

Comment: `.find(".dialog")` I can't find an element with class `dialog` in your jsfiddle markup.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').on('click','.ui-widget-overlay', function() {
    $('.ui-dialog').filter(function () {
    return $(this).css("display") === "block";
    }).find('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/VwCja/1/)

This works... Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14515351/1150613)