# Event for records not delete. Jtable Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dialog, jquery-jtable, delete-record

I am deleting in jquery jtable. It checks for constraint and returns an error. When i press close button of that error the deleteDialog reappears. I don't want the dialog to reappear, instead i want the dialog to be closed and the jtable to be loaded. Is there any recordsNotDeleted event in jtable? Please Help

[image]

On closing the Dialog with the title of Attention i want this dialog plus the dialog with the title of Are you sure? to be closed

Comment: Please put your code here so any one can help you.

Comment: Im looking for an event to fire when error comes

Comment: There is no such 'recordsNotDeleted' event in [JTable](http://www.jtable.org/)

Comment: so what can i do to implement one. Can you give me an idea?

Comment: @Sana if you can find out the Close button event of Attention dialogbox then you can reload the `JTable` explicitly using like this `$('#StudentTable').jtable('reload');`

Comment: Yes, but i am unable to find the event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This did the trick for me.

```
 $("button[role='button']:contains('Close')").click(function () {
        $('.ui-dialog').filter(function () {
            return $(this).css("display") === "block";
        }).find('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close');
    });
```

reference: [Close dialog on click (anywhere)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675893/close-dialog-on-click-anywhere)